# How can I use useEffect correctly in a function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I don't think I am using useEffect correctly in the function I have written. If I do the same with classes there is no problem and I am able to do ComponentDidMount(). But I don't know Hooks very well. So I think I am going wrong somewhere.

```
//import { onValue } from 'firebase/database';
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import {db} from '../../firebase';
import {ref,onValue} from 'firebase/database'
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

export default function NiftyChart() {
 React.useEffect(()=>{
    const dbRef=ref(db,"1rh1Ta-8dqZKmh1xy5ans2lOqReoiVAT81WyDKqRaxl0/Nifty");
    onValue(dbRef,(snapshot)=>{
      let records=[];
      snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot=>{
        let keyName=childSnapshot.key;
        let data=childSnapshot.val();
       console.log(snapshot.val());

        records.push({"key":keyName,"data":data})
        console.log(records[records.length-1])
      });
      this.setState();
 })
},[]); 
  
  
    return(
        
      <div>
{this.state.map((row, index)=>{
return(
<Box component="span" sx={{}}>
<Grid > {row.Close}</Grid>


</Box>
)
})}
</div>
    )
  }
```

Also, no value is printed for row.Close. In the console I seem to be getting  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state') this error.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For functional components there's no this.setState. Have a look at this https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `useState`:

```
const [records, setRecords] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => ..get records and set to state, []);
```

So code would look like this:

```
export default function MyComponent() {
  const [records, setRecords] = useState([]);
  

  useEffect(() => {
    // ... other code is omitted for the brevity
    setRecords(records)
  }, [])


  return(            
      <div>
          {records && 
              records.map((row, index)=>{ //...other code is omitted 
              // for the brevity }
      </div>
  )
}
```

[What's hook?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#whats-a-hook) The hook is:

> A Hook is a special function that lets you “hook into” React features.
> For example, useState is a Hook that lets you add React state to
> function components

`[]` in `useEffect` [means](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and
> unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This
> tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props
> or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special
> case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always
> works.

Read more about API call in [this great article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-call-web-apis-with-the-useeffect-hook-in-react)

Comment: this will loop, because `records` is a dependency

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava thanks for the sharp eye :). I've updated my reply. Please, see my updated answer

Comment: If I do setRecords(records) inside useEffect, it runs into an infinite loop. So I have put it outside useEffect.

Comment: records.map((row,index)=>{
        return(
            <Grid> {records.Close}</Grid>
        )
    }). Is this how I access my data elements? I seem to be getting this error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map').

Comment: @user460567 you can use empty dependency aray `useEffect(()=> {}, [])` to avoid infinite loop. And try to render if `record` is not undefined. I've added this check to my reply `records &&  records.map(( ...`